# Having problem to log into gmail?

Tags: .net, bots

i want to login to gmail using asp.net ,however when i use the http post method with ....

it returns your browser is not accepting cookies?...and in the internet explorer its sign's in ..whats the problem n what to look for ...And if any one has code how to login to gmail ...I will be very thankfull.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form  method="post" action="https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=mail" id="gaia_loginform">
 <input type="hidden" value="http://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&tab=wm" id="continue" name="continue"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="mail" id="service" name="service"/>

  Username:<input type="text"  value="" size="18" id="Email" name="Email"/>

  Password:<input type="password"  size="18" id="Passwd" name="Passwd"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="signIn"/>  

</form>
```

You can use google api also
http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/1.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#client_login

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to read this: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have signed into gmail with your IE therefore it has the cookie. if you want to login to gmail with ASP.NET you have to use a library like [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSharpGmail)

EDIT: if you need to login to Google adword you can use [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/)